# How can I sort with the data in another collection in mongo DB with one 2 many mapping with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collections in mongo DB -

1. vehicles
2. vehicle-pins

Here you can download the json of the collections -
[Download](https://easyupload.io/m/93wac9)

I want to join by stockid and sort by the description count, group by the description.type .
Means, there is a column in the UI named DAMAGE and if I sort with this field, then it will sort by the highest DAMAGE count. Your help will be appreciated.

Output should be like this -

```js
{
    "stockid": 62790,
    "condition": "Used",
    "vin": "WA1C4AFY1J2153426",
    "make": "Audi",
    "carYear": 2018,
    "carBody": "SUV",
    "model": "SQ5",
    "series": "3.0 TFSI Prestige",
    "mileage": 21861,
    "exteriorColor": "WHITE",
    "interiorColor": "DK RED",
    "fuelType": "Gasoline Fuel",
    "seating": "5",
    "listPrice": 35900,
    "damageCount": 5,
    "possibleFeatureCount": 1,
    "featureCount": 5
},
{
    "stockid": 62852,
    "condition": "Used",
    "vin": "WAU43AFD4HN017288",
    "make": "Audi",
    "carYear": 2017,
    "carBody": "Sedan",
    "model": "A8 L",
    "series": "4.0 TFSI Sport",
    "mileage": 32427,
    "exteriorColor": "WHITE",
    "interiorColor": "LT GRAY",
    "fuelType": "Gasoline Fuel",
    "seating": "5",
    "listPrice": 38900,
    "damageCount": 1,
    "possibleFeatureCount": 1,
    "featureCount": 2
},
{
    "stockid": 6740,
    "condition": "Used",
    "vin": "5TDKK3DC7GS751192",
    "make": "Toyota",
    "carYear": 2016,
    "carBody": "SUV",
    "model": "Sienna",
    "series": "5dr 7-Pass Van LE FWD",
    "mileage": 11111,
    "exteriorColor": "BLACK",
    "interiorColor": "LT GRAY",
    "fuelType": "Gasoline Fuel",
    "cylinder": "V6 Cylinder Engine",
    "seating": "7",
    "listPrice": 18900,
    "damageCount": 13,
    "possibleFeatureCount": 3,
    "featureCount": 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) for calculations and sorting.  I built a pipeline that I think meets your requirements.

```
[
{$unwind: {
  path: "$description"
}}, 
{$group: {
  _id: "$stockId",
  description: {
    $push: "$description"
  }
}}, 
{$lookup: {
  from: 'vehicles',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'stockid',
  as: 'vehicleInfo'
}}, 
{$addFields: {
  damageCount: {
    $size: {
      $filter: {
        input: '$description',
        as: 'desc',
        cond: {
          $eq: [
            '$$desc.type',
            'DAMAGE'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}, 
{$sort: {
  damageCount: -1
}}
]
```

The first thing the pipeline does is unwind the description array.  I do this since the same stockid can appear multiple times.

The $group stage then groups the documents based on the `stockid`. All of the items from the original description array are pushed to a new description field.

The $lookup stage joins the `vehicles` collection and the `vehicle-pins` collection on the `stockId`.  This stage puts information from the `vehicles` collection in an array named `vehicleInfo`.

The $addFields stage adds a field to each document named `damageCount` that counts how many elements in the description have a type equal to `DAMAGE`.

The $sort stage sorts the documents by the new `damageCount` field in descending order.

I'm including screenshots below of the pipeline in MongoDB Atlas so you can see what is happening in each stage.

Note: when I imported your documents into Atlas, the stockid's were not of the same type in both collections.  One of the stockid's was of type string and the other was of type int32.  The $lookup stage didn't work until I made them all the same type.  If you do not want to update the documents themselves, you could add a stage to the pipeline to do the conversion: [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/).

[image: Screenshot of pipeline]

[image: Screenshot of pipeline]

Comment: Here is the complete query =>
let vehiclesList = await VehicleModel.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "features",
          "localField": "features",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "features"
        }
      },
      {
       "$unwind": {
         "path": "$features",
         "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields" : {
            "modifierId" : { "$toString": "$stockid"}
        }
      },

Comment: {
        "$lookup": {
          "localField": "modifierId",
          "from": "vehicle-pins",
          "foreignField": "stockId",
          "as": "vehiclePins"
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields" : {
            "installedPossibleFeatures" : "$features.installedPossibleFeatures"
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields" : {
            "possibleFeatures" : "$features.possibleFeatures"
        }
      },

Comment: {"$addFields": {
        "totalDamageCount": {
            "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$vehiclePins.description",
                "as": "desc",
                "cond": { "$eq": ["$$desc.type", "DAMAGE"]}
              }
            }
        }
      }}, 
      {
        "$match": findParams
      },
      
      { "$sort":  sortParams },
      { "$skip": (page) * resultPerPage },
      { "$limit": resultPerPage },
    ]);

Comment: It's hard for me to guess what's going wrong by looking at the stages above.  I recommend you create the aggregation pipeline in MongoDB Atlas or MongoDB Compass, so you can see what is happening in each stage.  This should help you identify where things aren't working. I'm guessing one of my field names didn't exactly match yours.  I've added screenshots to my answer above so you can compare your pipeline to mine.

Comment: I have one to many relation in vehicle-pins. For 1 vehicle i have multiple vehicle pins objects in db. So when I am doing this -
{$addFields: {
  damageCount: {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$description",
          "as": "desc",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$desc.type", "DAMAGE"]}
        }
      }
  }
}}
It is showing damage count as 0. It is working fine if there is only one vehicle-pin for a vehicle. So I have to collect all the vehicle-pins description and insert into one array and pass it to  "input". Can you help me how can i do this ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you update your question to have json documents for each collection, including enough documents to show the 1 to Many relationship?  It's unclear to me how they are being matched.  Can you also include your desired output?

Comment: I have updated the question with json collections and desired output.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your updates to the question.